# Olympiad physics 1996 problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I don't understand the [official solution](http://www.raunvis.hi.is/~martin/ipho/ipho_problems/ipho_1996_T1-S.pdf) of the first problem of the 1996 International Physics Olympiad.

They give this circuit:

[image]

Each black box is a resistor of resistance $1\Omega$.
They then claim that the following circuit is equivalent:

[image]

I no not see the equivalence.
Why are these two equivalent and what principle(s) is(are) used to understand the equivalence?

Comment: Please include the relevant portions of the link into the question to protect against link rot.

Comment: Have you tried doing the problem yourself?

Comment: The easiest way to prove (or to figure out) equivalent circuits is to label all endpoints of wires and make sure that if $X$ and $Y$ are connected in one circuit by a resistor, they should be connected in equivalent one too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Start with the initial diagram, but let's color code everything:

[image]

Now move some wires around, without actually changing the connectivity:

[image]

Finally, rotate the left and right blocks while again not changing the connectivity:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly move lines (which are assumed to have no resistance) around by continuous movements. Try to see how to go from the first picture to the second one by this sort of operations, that is, stretching/squeezing/identifying lines with same potential