# The equivalent resistance betweeen A and B. I need the answer with proper explaination

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

how are we supposed to do this question if resistance is given as 1 ohm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Olympiad physics 1996 problem](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162639/olympiad-physics-1996-problem). It's not *exactly* the same question, but the same method works.

Comment: could u explain pls

Comment: This looks very much like a homework or exam question. You should show some effort to solve it rather than just posting the bare question and waiting for the community to give you the solution. You can find some information on homework questions [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two basic options:

1. Realize that this is actually just two resistors in series with three parallel resistors, and analyze it using the equivalent resistances of resistors in parallel and series, or
2. Use Kirchoff's laws to derive the equivalent resistance.

If you choose option 1, I'll help you out by revealing the parallel resistors in this weirdly drawn network. I've labeled the resistors 1-5 from left to right to make the transformation easier to follow:

Starting arrangement:

[image: Starting arrangement]

Step 1 - rotate R2 counterclockwise by 90°:

[image: Step 1 - rotate R2 counterclockwise by 90°]

Step 2 - rotate R3 clockwise by 90°:

[image: Step 2 - rotate R3 clockwise by 90°]

Step 3 - rotate R4 counterclockwise by 90°:

[image: Step 3 - rotate R4 counterclockwise by 90°]

Voila - a familiar-looking network.